# Can I set up my Linux Home directory on a different partition

Tags: linux-mint

I've had a disk crash and I'm about to replace my HDD (SAT III) on my notebook with a SSD and a HDD and I want to set up the OS (Mint 17.1) & WIN 7 Home Premium  (both 64 bit) on the SSD and make them bootable and place my HOME directoy on to the HDD. I then want to restore the saved image of my boot directory and WIN 7 partitions to the SSD and my home directory to the HDD, all of which I have located on a USB HDD backup.

The partition that was causing the problem with my present HDD was the environment where MINT 17.1 was located and I don't have a satisfactory backup of that so I need to install that on to the SSD.

I have a rescue disk which amongst other things contains gparted and the necessary software to do the restores.

Comment: `mount /external/home /home/allen`

Answer (score 0):

Try `man usermod` of your distro.

Usually with `usermod -m --home <NEW_PLACE>`, the new place is set and all the content is moved.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a different partition to the `/home` directory. But the directory has to be empty for that. To do the mount automatically you can edit you `/etc/fstab` and add a new entry for this partition.

Use `blkid` to get the uuid of the partition you want to mount.

Add the following line to you `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=<uuid>     /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Copy the content of your home directory to the root of your new partition. Move the current home to a backup:

```
cd / && sudo mv /home /home_backup && sudo mkdir /home
```

At the end reboot your system.